# C# - Double quotes in SQL commandtext

Tags: c#, vertica

I'm writing a program about execute an query and display results in datagridview, the query is like:
select * from "20000_es_asset".tablename;
DB is HP Vertica, here's my C# code:

```
string strAsset = @"""20000_es_asset""";
string strSQL = "select * from " + strAsset + "." + table + ";";
VerticaCommand command = _conn.CreateCommand();
command.CommandText = strSQL;
```

There are two double quotes in strSQL, the problem is, it seemed like CommandText didn't parse escape character and straight moved, debug info of the CommandText is:
select * from \"20000_es_asset\".tablename;
Exception: “Vertica.Data.VerticaClient.VerticaException” in Vertica.Data.dll, [42601] ERROR: Syntax error
How could I get rid of this "\"? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Tried [String.Format Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: You might want to try and use [`QUOTENAME`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176114.aspx) to safely escape the names. Then feed the output of that in to a `sp_executesql`

Comment: Thank you Yang & Scott, It's OK now, just found that my query was wrong, not caused by double quotes. what a shame!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string strSQL = string.Format("select * from {0}.{1};", "\"20000_es_asset\"", table);
```

PS- You should always make your query parametrized.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the the double quotes "" in strAsset using square brackets[]

```
string strAsset = @"[""20000_es_asset""]";
string strSQL = "select * from " + strAsset + "." + table + ";";
VerticaCommand command = _conn.CreateCommand();
command.CommandText = strSQL;
```

Comment: If you add square braketes `select * from ["20000_es_asset"].table` is a valid name.

Comment: @scott , yes ofcourse , my fault , to early for answers , have edited it now :)

Comment: Thank you Thorarins. It's OK now, just found that my query was wrong, not caused by double quotes. what a shame!